# What needs to be true of $f$ for $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$?

Tags: calculus

What conditions does a function $f$ have to fulfill in order that:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}) $?

I am trying to prove something else, and I have just got it down to this bit, which is usually true, but I'm not sure what was to be true of $f$ for this to be true. Continuity? Differentiable?

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: [Clairaut's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Clairaut.27s_theorem) states that *if* $f$ has continuous second order partial derivatives, then those derivatives must be equal.  *However*, this is a *sufficient condition* on the equality of the second derivatives.  Strictly speaking, your question asks for a *necessary* condition.  Perhaps, that's harder.

Comment: Twice differentiable is enough (it's a little weaker then the continuity of the second order mixed partial derivatives).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Clairaut's Theorem**:

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a real-valued function defined on all of ${\mathbb R^2}$. Suppose further that the second-order mixed partial derivatives $f_{xy}(x,y)$ and $f_{yx}(x,y)$ both *exist* and are *continuous* on ${\mathbb R^2}$. Then $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ on all of ${\mathbb R^2}$.

- The same result applies if $f$ and its derivatives exist and are continuous on an open subset of ${\mathbb R^2}$.
- This result can be generalized to higher-order derivatives and to functions of more than two variables.

Answer (score 5):

Clairaut's Theorem is definitely the most commonly used version of the theorem, but you may like to know a slightly more general case in which it still holds. This version usually goes by the name of Schwarz Theorem:

> **Theorem (Schwarz)** Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $x_0 \in E^\circ$ and assume that for some $i,j$ there is $B(x_0,r) \subseteq E$ such that for all $x \in B(x_0,r)$ all of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x), \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x), \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}(x)$ exist. If $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x_0)$ exists and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}(x_0) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x_0)$.

In **plain english**: if $f_x,f_y, f_{xy}$ exist near $x_0$ and $f_{xy}$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $f_{xy}(x_0)=f_{yx}(x_0)$.

Note that in the case that $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are everywhere continuous, Clairaut's Theorem follows.

Comment: It is Schwarz, not Laurent Schwartz.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if $f$ has continuous second partial derivatives at any given point (so it needs to be both continuous and twice differentiable)

Comment: Clairaut's Theorem?

Comment: might be the "twice" differentiable was to informal?

Comment: yes, but I made a quick answer when there were none, and just in case he/she was interested in the straight answer. But thanks for the advice, I'll use it.